# remove bracket, double quote, and possibly add space using string.replaceall in java

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I saw multiple thread answering about how to replace/remove single quote ('), double quote ("), bracket ([,{), commas, etc. While I was able to successfully remove them, but I would like to understand more. For example, string.replaceAll("\p{P}",""); can remove the punctuations. I am confused about this syntax; how does "\p{P}","" is equal to punctuations?

I have a string that I would like to remove bracket, double quote, and possibly add space. As shown below, I would like to use replaceAll to change my string from category to updatedCategory.

```
String category = "["restaurant","bar","burger joint"]";
String updatedCategory = "restaurant, bar, burger joint";
```

Comment: Those string patterns are called "regex" (short for "regular expression") and there are many many tutorials on the web.  Please search with Google.  Java's particular syntax is [documented in the `Pattern` class.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: However, be aware that a lot of folks don't like regular expressions and overuse is almost certainly an anti pattern. https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about regex, for your problem you can use `replaceAll` with this regex [`["\[ \]]`](https://regex101.com/r/6QZdr0/1) like this:

```
category.replaceAll("[\"\\[ \\]]", "")
```

The output will be:

```
restaurant,bar,burgerjoint
```

So to get the same `updatedCategory` just use:

```
category.replaceAll("[\"\\[ \\]]", "")
    .replace(",", ", ")
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask for the .replace(",", ", "), is that supposed to add the space between the commas?

Comment: @BrianMcCanaugh yes exactly

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a reason why I need to separate .replaceAll and .replace?

Comment: To not complete the regex and make it more readable.